# Optimize Nested Linq to SQL Query

Tags: optimization, linq-to-sql, nested

I've got a linq to sql query that I'm trying to optimize.  I've tracked down a major issue which relates to the number of sql queries being called to the database.  Because of the nested nature of the query - it's huge! (try 14,000 lines in SQL profiler). Ouch!

I'm looking at eager loading and using LoadWith - but there appears to be a limitation with nested queries? (Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Cycles not allowed in LoadOptions LoadWith type graph.).  Any ideas on how to get Linq to SQL to load some of the related data and have fewer db hits?  thanks!

```
        List<EBCFPS> ebcfpsList = (from c in v3
                                                                    group c by c.CId into g
                                                                    select new EBCFPS()
                                                                    {
                                                                        CId = g.First().CId,
                                                                        CName = g.First().CName,
                                                                        CType = g.First().CType,
                                                                        SortOrder = g.First().SortOrder == null ? 0 : (int)g.First().SortOrder,
                                                                        EsGroup = (from q in g
                                                                                         select new EFPS()
                                                                                         {
                                                                                             EId = (int)q.EId,
                                                                                             EName = q.EName,
                                                                                             CESGroup = (from s in db.CES
                                                                                                              where s.EId == q.EId
                                                                                                              && s.CId == q.CId
                                                                                                              select new CESSFPS()
                                                                                                              {
                                                                                                                  CESId = s.CESId,
                                                                                                                  CId = s.CId,
                                                                                                                  EId = s.EId == null ? 0 : (int)s.EId,
                                                                                                                  FSCId = s.FSCId == null ? 0 : (int)s.FSCId,
                                                                                                                  SEV = s.SEV,
                                                                                                                  Score = s.Score
                                                                                                              }).ToList()
                                                                                         }).ToList()
                                                                    }).ToList();
```

Sorry the code is a bit gnarly to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was compiled queries.